# pass value from two different subroutines to a new subroutine: Perl

Tags: perl

I'm facing a problem with passing values from two different subroutines to another subroutines. I've seen some posts where people suggested removing `use strict; use warnings` but I know it's not a good practice, even more I need to face many problems if I did. What I want to do is

```
sub mol_wt{

         ...

         ...
    &ext_coeff($molWt);

}

sub absorbance{

      .....

      .....

      &ext_coeff($absorbance);

}

sub ext_coeff{

      my($wt, $abs) = @_;

}
```

Last subroutine is receiving only one value. How can I pass values from first two subroutines to last one?

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to do. I guess you're calculating an extinction coefficient from an absorbance and a molecular weight, but you need to have *both* of those values when you do the calculation.

Comment: yep. I have calculated both of those values in first two subroutines and passing them to last one.

Comment: But you're calling the subroutine twice with one parameter at a time. That isn't going to work. You can only call `ext_coeff` when you have *both* values

Comment: That is what the problem is. I'm a tyro in programming. Then how can I pass two values from first two subroutines to last subroutines?

Answer (score 0):

Use an anomymous hash:

```
sub mol_wt{
    ...
    ext_coeff({molWt => $molWt});
}

sub absorbance{
    ...
    ext_coeff({absorbance => $absorbance});
}

sub ext_coeff{
    my $params = shift;
    ...
    my $wt  = $params->{molWt};
    my $abs = $params->{absorbance};
    ...
}
```

Comment: Use of uniinitialized $wt and $abs. How can I overcome this

Comment: @VenuThatikonda: Test if they are defined defined before using them.